# Flash: prevent the user from draging one thumb of a HSlider

Tags: apache-flex, flash, components

I'm using Flash HSlider component.
I used a slider with several thumbs. I'd like to prevent the user from draging just the middle thumb, but can drag other thumbs. I don't know how to do it. Could any one can give me some tips?

Thanks.

Yuan

Answer (score 1):

on creation complete for the slider do...

```
slider.getThumbAt(middleThumbIndex).enabled = false;
```